# AppleTV Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group on UIFoundation

Tags: swift, apple-tv

i'm building https://github.com/jvanakker/tvOSBrowser <- this browser project for Apple TV (4th gen), OS 11.3. Xcode 9.3 (stable) and i get following error:

```
ld: in 

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation', missing required architecture arm64 in file
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation (2 slices) for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On AppleTV simulator it works quite well, but on actual hardware it fails...